# I am new to Selenium IDE. I want to delete a dynamically generated record in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-ide

I want to delete a record if the record has 'TFrist TLast' in xpath=//span[@id='lblGuestName']. I used to assert and store commands to verify the label exists and store that value in the variable. Now I want to click the delete link for that record.

Please help.

Please see the below image for the desired outcome.

[image]

Below is the image of the commands in the IDE. The highlighted one is hardcoded but I need to fetch the index and delete the record.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello Ajeet, Thanks but there are just commands on IDE. Ther's no code snippet to reproduce.